# Regex to include a pattern match and not include another but not immediately following

Tags: regex

I have currently a pattern match in a query like this

```
if(upper(email_omni_code_mini) like '%TRAVEL%' and upper(email_omni_code_mini) NOT like '%TRAVEL%ENS%',...,...)
```

I want to change this to a single pattern match but this won't work
    `TRAVEL(?!ENS)` as ENS is not immediately following.

Is there a way to solve this easily.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If there are other chars in between, insert `.*` before `ENS`. Use `TRAVEL(?!.*ENS)`

Comment: Oh okay , I was of the impression that variable no of characters wont work in look ahead. Was brushing up this after a long time.

Comment: Add that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are other chars in between, insert `.*` before `ENS`:

```
TRAVEL(?!.*ENS)
```

It will now match `TRAVEL` that is not immediately followed with any 0+ chars as many as possible followed with `ENS` substring.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8By9xr/1).